# PyTorch and applying dense nets for MNIST

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am trying to apply dense nets in pytorch for MNIST dataset classification.
But there is a problem with sizing, is there any parameter for MNIST dataset in dense nets (vgg, alexnet, densenet and etc) or we should modify the source code?

Thanks

Comment: You should state more clearly what you want to achieve and provide some [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I applied alexnet for MNIST data set after I changes the parameters in the net to make size working. Is this the only way to do that or such deep nets have options for MNIST too?

Comment: Probably you have to consider either: to scale the image before feeding it to the netowrk or to change the kernel size of the last average pooling layer before the fully connected layer (so it flattens the output) in the dense net model.

Comment: MNIST is a quite simple dataset, maybe you do not need to classify the dataset image with densenet.